# How can I make emacs libraries use request.el instead of url.el?

Tags: http, curl, emacs

Some libraries, e.g. xml-rpc, directly use `url-retrieve`. I want them to instead use [`request.el`](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-request), so that I can choose `curl` as my backend. Is there an easy shim-layer I can install?

I'm looking for something like [`curl-for-url`](https://github.com/nicferrier/curl-url-retrieve), which transparently rebinds `url-http` with a compatible implementation. (`curl-for-url` itself doesn't actually work very well, though.)

Comment: You can redefine or advise `url-retrieve` to be anything you want (probably best to use advice, so that it can be easily *removed* as well). Either way you will need to write a function which maintains compatibility with the `url-retrieve` API but calls something equivalent in request.el instead (and that's not a standard library, so please provide a link to the source). If request.el *already* has a compatible function, most of the work is done for you. You might indicate which request.el function(s) you anticipate using?

Comment: Thanks. I added the link to request.el. It doesn't look like its API is compatible, so what I'm asking is whether someone has already written this glue layer, and if so, how I could find it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know whether such a thing exists already. The request.el readme does say it can use either `curl` or `url-retrieve` as a back end, which suggests that code for mapping the abilities of `request` to `url-retrieve` exists, and could be reversed. The question then is whether request.el actually supports *all* of the abilities of `url-retrieve`? If not, you wouldn't be able to do what you're trying to do as a *general* change (but could probably detect cases which were supported, and switch handlers conditionally). Otherwise, I imagine this could indeed be done generally.

Comment: Perhaps you should report the issues you've experienced with `curl-for-url` to its author, however.

Comment: An answer mentioning https://github.com/dochang/mb-url was added but then deleted, so I'm adding this comment preserve the reference.  Moderators: I disagree with the deletion of that answer.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes, but if that particular linked page goes away, so does the solution -- at which point anything describing how to use that solution in more detail would still be useless (unless it quoted the entire source code of the library).  Please restore the (useful, AFAICS) answer, as I'm unable to do so myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using advice, but you will need to use the
ad-get-arg/ad-get-args functions to extract the arguments url-retrieve was
called with and determine how you want to process them and pass them to the
retrieve function. The one which will likely be problematic is the callback
function. However, provided you can setup the buffer with the downloaded
data in the same way, with the same name as url-retrieve, you should be able to
apply the callback manually after the call to request and you have setup the
buffers as necessary.

It will be a fair bit of work and you will need to dig deep into both the url.el
and request.el libraries. It is also likely to be a bit fragile.

One concern I would have is the use of monkey patching by request.el. From the
project page, it looks like this code has not been updated since Emacs version
25.1 and the current official emacs is 25.2. This is one of the problems with
monkey patching - you need to keep versions in sync to avoid version
incompatibility issues.

It also seems odd to me to have someone who has patches to fix known bugs if
those patches have not been applied to the mainstream version - especially when
there has been a more recent release of the mainstream version.

The first thing I would do is upgrade to emacs 25.2 and then determine if using
request.el is as justified. I would also verify the problems you experience are
actually due to url-retrieve or are perhaps due to callbacks being passed to
that function. If it is a problem with the callbacks, you may be better off
using advice to fix those callbacks rather than replace the underlying
problems.

If you only have issues in some situations where url-retrieve is used, it may
also be easier to go up one level and look at the things which are using it and
perhaps use something like advice to replace the call to url-retrieve with
request at that level.

Someone might be able to provide more specific recommendations if you provide
more detail on the precise reasons you cannot or do not want to use the
url.el library.